# test etherchannel load-balance command doesn't work

Tags: networking, cisco-catalyst, etherchannel, port-channel

I am trying to learn the etherchannel environment but when I enter this command it gives an error.

```
Switch#test etherchannel load-balance interface po1 mac 00d0.ba86.1e19 00d0.ba86.1e1a
        ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.
```

I tried this command on 2960 and 3560 but it still didn't work

I guess this command is for newer versions but I still tried and it didn't work again

```
show etherchannel load-balance hash-result interface port-channel
```

Comment: It is available on high end models, like 6500 series switches. The ones you tried don't support this command. You can verify this by typing t? and it will give you list of commands that are supported starting with letter 't'

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

That command is not available on those models.

Comment: Is it old or new? Because that's what CCNA 200-301 showed in their book.